# MapReduce in Haskell

Tags: haskell, mapreduce

I'm trying to implement the `MapReduce` function. I have to do it without any parallelism, I have this so far:

```
import Data.Map
import Data.Char

map_ list = toList $ fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- list]

main_ = map_ $ getWords "test.txt" --getting error here

prettyprint [(x, y):xs] =  x ++ " : " ++ y -- trying to print out list

-- Loads words from a text file into a list.
getWords :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getWords path = do contents <- readFile path
               return ([map toLower x | x <- words contents]) --- Ambiguous occurrence `map'
```

The main task is to use `MapReduce` to get a list of words from a file and the frequency of every new word.

**I don't understand how the reduce works in this case. I just know that I am mapping a list to a function that calculates the frequency of the words. How can it be reduced?**

Comment: I strongly suggest you add type signatures to every top-level definition. This will make your code partially documented, and the compiler will produce better type errors.

Answer (score 4):

Just addressing your compilation problems...

Both the `Prelude` and `Data.Map` define the function `map`.

A good way to fix the ambiguity is to qualify the import of `Data.Map` like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
```

and then use `M.map` to refer to the function in `Data.Map` and plain `map` to refer to the Prelude version.

The problem in `main_` is that `getWords` is an `IO [String]`, so you need to extract the list with the `<-` operator before you can use it:

```
main_ = do ws <- getWords
           -- do something with ws
           print $ map_ ws
```